# Using custom check box , call function onto its changed event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Custom  checkbox
[image]

Html of  this

[image]

CSS for this

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
position: absolute; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height:1px; 
 width:1px; 
  margin:-1px; 
 padding:0;
 border:0;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
padding-left:20px;
height:15px; 
display:inline-block;
line-height:15px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
font-size:15px;
vertical-align:middle;
cursor:pointer;
}


input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
background-position: 0 -15px;
}

.css-label{
background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/dark-check-green.png);
 }
```

http://csscheckbox.com/  this is  link for reference  from where i take the custom  checkbox
No i  want to call a function if  checkbox is  checked 
What i i have currently done

```
$("#coverage_checkbox").click(function () {
  var  a =  $(this).is("checked");
});
```

but  it is returing  false every time

Comment: first u check $("#coverage_checkbox").click(function () {
  alert('test')
}); is working or not

Comment: I have resolved the above by using   $(this).attr("checked")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/x32r9/

**JS:-**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#checkboxn01").on("change",function(){
        alert($(this).is(":checked"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#coverage_checkbox").click(function () {
  var  a =  $(this).is(":checked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an if-statement around your `$(this).is("checked")` variable and add your function in between.

http://jsfiddle.net/rxjpC/1/

Answer (score 0):

According to the CSS on the page, the real checkbox is set to 1x1 size,when you change the checkbox icon, you should change the real checkbox status